# Adding newline when generating XML with XML::LibXML in Perl

Tags: perl, libxml2

I am using the Perl [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aLibXML) module to create XML files.

I am not able to add newlines to the output XML file.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please show your program, the output, and how you would like it to look

Answer (score 4):

You have said nothing about how you are producing the output, but have you looked at the second parameter to `toFile`?

Something like

```
 $doc->toFile('myfile.xml', 1)
```

should help.